# retrieve tokens in lark python

Tags: python, regex, lark-parser

so I'm using the Lark library in python to parse some text and I'm facing 2 problems.
I searched in the documentation but I couldn't find a way to retrieve tokens from a tree, and the second one is that I was expecting a Tree with multiple tokens, but instead of it, I got nested trees where each tree has only one token.

here's my code:

```py
l = Lark('''start: EXPERT "arguments with" arg _NL
            EXPERT : /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
            ARGUMENT : /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
            arg: ARGUMENT","arg | ARGUMENT
            %import common.WORD   // imports from terminal library
            %ignore " "           // Disregard spaces in text
            %import common.NEWLINE -> _NL
         ''',parser='lalr', lexer='contextual')
```

the result I got:

```py
Tree(start, [Token(EXPERT, 'PC1'), Tree(arg, [Token(ARGUMENT, 'a'), Tree(arg, [Token(ARGUMENT, 'b'), Tree(arg, [Token(ARGUMENT, 'c')])])])])
```

the result i was expecting :

```py
Tree(start, [Token(EXPERT, 'PC1'), Tree(arg, [Token(ARGUMENT, 'a'),Token(ARGUMENT, 'b'),Token(ARGUMENT, 'c')])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `arg: ARGUMENT","arg | ARGUMENT` to `arg: ARGUMENT ("," arg)*` which is equivalent.

The `*` means: match 0 or more instances. With this notation, lark will treat the elements as a list.